# JMockit `Mockup` class returns null for own new instances from within itself

Tags: java, jmockit

**Description**:
Trying to mock this class (from some library):

```
public class Signal{

   public static Signal fromPool(){
      // returns a recycled instance from a signal pool
   }

   public int getCode(){
     // returns some signal code;
   }
}
```

Class `Sender` uses `Signal.fromPool()` internally :

```
public class Sender{
   private Signal sig;

   public void ready(){
     sig = Signal.fromPool();
     System.out.println(sig);
   }

   public void send(OutputStream output){
      output.write(sig.getCode());
   }
}
```

And we need to write some unit tests for `Sender`.

**But**, In Unit test environment, `Signal.fromPool()` will fail, because environment lacks some internal dependencies.

Hence, we decide to use "JMockit" to mock `Signal` class:

```
public class SenderTest{

   // mock signal class
   static class MockSignal extends Mockup<Signal>{

      @Mock
      public static Signal fromPool(){
         return new Signal();
      }

      @Mock
      public int getCode(){
         return 42;
      }
   }

   @Test
   public void testSending(@Mocked OutputStream stream){
       // replace Signal with MockSignal
       new MockSignal();

       // should write 42
       new Expectations(){{
          stream.write(42);
       }};

       // test code
       Sender sender = new Sender();
       sender.ready();
       sender.send(stream);
   }
}
```

**Problem**: Mocked `Signal.fromPool` returns a `null`. This statement in above code prints `null`:

```
     System.out.println(sig);
```

My understanding is that perhaps inside the mocked `fromPool` the Mocked class itself isn't being instantiated:

```
  @Mock
  public static Signal fromPool(){
     return new Signal();
  }
```

How can `new Signal` return `null` ? Anyone has a better perspective ?

Comment: @AdrianShum Please read the question again. Its not about how to mock static methods.

Comment: Please read the link, it seems that you are mocking the static method wrong, hence not giving proper result.  However I need to admit that I am not a JMockIt user, I just happened to find the wrong syntax base on a previous question

Comment: @AdrianShum Actually, I'm following : http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#mocks And same approach has worked for me in other tests and with other classes.

Comment: You mean for the static mocking part?  But from what I found, when you use JMockit `@Mock` to mock a static method, you should annotate it on the method WITHOUT `static` classifier (as mentioned in the link I shown and http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.in/2012/06/jmockit-tutoriallearn-it-today-with.html#static_method), for which you seems doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure the example test code does not work? Because for me it's working fine (the test passes). Check for any error messages in standard output, in case JMockit is failing to initialize itself.

Comment: @Rogério Thanks for your response. It was much simpler actually, `@Mocked Signal sig` as a test function parameter and setting the `result = sig` in expectations block. The real reason `new Signal` was returning null was because the runtime platform itself returns null for the constructor. I thought I would never be able to create a new instance, but @Mocked annotation did  got me a mock instance to use in test. I'm just exploring JMockit, its awesome so far.